# Destroy method doesn't work when using custom routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

```
#routes.rb
map.connect '/articles/new', :controller => 'articles', :action => 'new'
map.connect '/articles/:author_name', :controller => 'articles', :action => 'show'
map.connect '/articles/:author_name/edit', :controller => 'articles', :action => 'edit'

map.resources :articles, :comments
```

When I got to /articles/test and click delete, it does nothing. I'm guessing my custom routes are preventing it, how do I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: How are you setting up the test route and what does your `link_to`/`button_to` code that initiates the Delete look like?

Comment: I'm using whatever what is in the scaffold. I don't think its that, its the damn routes.

Comment: From the code you've posted, you don't have a /articles/test route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to rethink what you are doing here.

I would rely on the path prefix instead of defining overlapping routes:

```
map.resources :articles, :path_prefix => '/articles/:author_name', :name_prefix => 'article_'
```

That or see if you can define your resource like this:

```
map.resources :articles, :belongs_to => :author
```

I know you can do that with a :has_many and you get the namespacing you want, but not positive about belongs_to.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was doing that was before I couldn't get to params to work. Or more specifically Rails won't find it.

```
#Articles controller
@article = Article.find_by_name(params[:name])

#Article model
def to_param
  name
end  def to_param
name
```

end

I looked around and they all say to do that, but it won't work for me for some reason. I get `Couldn't find Article with ID=test` error.